# Ham Variable Lab Power Supply

Tags: mobile, power-supply, dc-power

I'm looking into purchasing a mobile radio ([TYT TH-9800](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00I53VUEY)) for my Jeep Wrangler. I am hoping to be able to use it in my apartment as well.

Since I'm going to need a power supply for this, I think it would be great to pick one up that can double as a variable lab supply (since I don't yet own one and would like to use it for tinkering and other projects).

The non-variable one recommended was
[http://www.amazon.com/23-Amp-Desktop-Switching-Power-Supply/dp/B0002D6KOU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002D6KOU)

Can you suggest a power supply that might be a good choice for this? Will I need special cables to connect my mobile radio to my PS?

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic here. Please edit your question to be purely about the general idea and "what should I look for" and not ask for suggestions.

Comment: Also, to quickly answer your last sub-question since it's independent: your radio will likely come with _bare wire ends_. You are expected to attach appropriate connectors yourself. Common choices are 1/4" ring terminals (for binding posts as most power supplies have) or Anderson PowerPole connectors.

Comment: I think you'll find that a "good" regulated lab supply that can supply 20+ amps is going to cost more than a fixed voltage 20A supply plus a lab regulated 3 - 5A supply, so unless you really need the high amperage in a variable supply, you might be better off with two separate power supplies.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comment by @Johnny -- you should get fixed voltage for the ham equipment and separate lower amperage for the tinkering needs.  If you are just tinkering with solid-state circuits that might need 3, 5 or 12 volts than consider one of those cheap industrial multi-voltage fixed supplies.  These are switching power supplies with regulated voltage outputs typically 5 volts and 12 volts.  If you need something else like 3 volts than do like I do, I use D-cell batteries that I keep there on my tinkering bench.  You can pick up these types of supplies for about \$15 to \$25 on Ebay or Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

powerwerx.com has a 30 amp variable desktop power supply (SKU:SPS-30DM) which has a switch to set as single voltage or as variable.  It's also very small and won't take up much room on your desk.
For cables, I always change mine to Anderson powerpoles.  You can get them from the same site.  You need to be handy with a crimper to make the cables, but you should be able to buy a cable ready-made for your radio.

Comment: I have the Powerwerx power supply described above (with meters) and it is nice because it is small and light.  I also use Answerson Powerpoles.  Even though it has a variable voltage feature, I have never used that feature with this supply as I have a bunch of other power supplies I use that satisfy common voltage needs (as explained in my answer posted here).

Comment: @K7PEH That would be *Anderson* Powerpoles, not Answerson :)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling  -- yes, it is almost as if my keyboard has an evil life of its own.